# Java jar for 12c

Tags: oracle, jdbc

we are using jdbc 11.1.0.6 jar in our application(running in JDK7) for working with 11g databse. Now we are migrating from 11g datatase to 12c. Can we still use the same 11.1.0.6 jar for working with 12c database?

Comment: See the [Oracle JDBC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02)

Comment: Why not just upgrade to the latest driver?

Comment: As the tomcat container provider is not ready to change the version of jdbc driver(currently 11.1.0.6), we have to stick with this instead of 12c driver.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can without a problem. Older clients can connect to new server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that, but it's always better to use the recommended one. For Oracle 12c, you can find the jdbc drivers at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html

Answer (score 1):

Clients of one major version can usually connect to servers of the next major version, with some limits. Beyond that, it's less frequently true.

Even with a successful connection, newer data types, network, security, and other features may not be supported with the older client, and results of trying to use them may be unpredictable.

It's always best to use a client version matching the target server version; in this case, [found here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html).